# How do I delete images from disk using feh?

Tags: feh

I use feh to view images on my hard drive. However, if I hit [delete] the images are removed from the current slideshow, but not from the disk. What is the right way of removing images from the drive straight from feh?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From `man feh`

> `CTRL+delete [delete]`
>
> Remove current file from filelist and delete it

`CTRL+delete` will do the job

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, the keys are:

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> while looking at the image you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mentioning that you can configure your keybindings so the `delete` key actually removes the files from the disk. This is how you can do it:

- create a `keys` file in the `~/.config/feh/` directory:

`touch ~/.config/feh/keys`

- edit that file so it has the following content:

```
delete Delete
remove C-Delete
```

By doing that, now the `delete` key will remove your file from the disk whereas the `<Ctrl+Delete>` key will remove it from the current slideshow.

For more information, please do `man feh` and read the manual.